# Incrementation doesn't go further than 0x01

Tags: c, debugging, increment, microcontroller, iar

So I've got functions:

```
int f1(uint8_t* a, int b)
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        f2(&a[i]);

    return 1;
}

static void f2(uint8_t* a)
{
    REG1 = *a;
    ...
    *a = REG2;
}
```

"a" is a data register that is used as a buffer to put the data all the way from the main loop into the target function f2() through different wrapper functions.

"REG1" and "REG2" are I/O registers into and out of which the data is passed with "a". The value of "REG2" implicitly changes while in f2() through hardware operations.

When I watch the variable changes in debug mode, the following happens:

> 1. b = 2
> 2. declare i = 0, i < b
> 3. call f2
> 4. increment i to i = 1, i < b
> 5. call f2
> 6. increment i to i = **0**, i < b

And since "i" never reaches 2, the loop never ends. The program is compiled and debugged with IAR EW for AVR. The optimisation for the compiler is turned off.

Comment: What is `a` outside `f1()`, and what does `f2()` do? Show more code.

Comment: You're a bit stingy showing your code :), what is `REG2`?

Comment: Added info about the registers.

Comment: Yes but we still don't see where REG2 gets its data

Comment: This seems to be an obvious memory corruption bug. I don't think you are passing the right parameters to the function. You are probably passing the address of a pointer instead of a pointer, or similar. Impossible to tell with the code posted.

Comment: Is it possible that your REG1 holds 'i' data?

Comment: This looks like (for some reason) that it is compiling as `f2((&a)[i]);` and you are just iterating through your stack variables. What is b's value through all this. I would suspect b to have changed value after line 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lundin is correct, I was passing an address of a pointer instead of the pointer itself with:

```
f2(&a[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Lundin says, it seems that memory corruption bug.

If you can use debugger, try inserting write-watchpoint on `i`. It might help you ^o^

(When thinking about only these codes, I can assume that `a` is corrupted, and `*a = REG2;` might write on stack, and eventually `i` is changed)